# SSL WebSocket connection not working with webkit browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have installed Let's Encypt (https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate for my web server (Apache) and WebSocket server (PHPWS).
Problem is that SSL WebSocket is working fine with Firefox but fails to work with Chrome, Chromium and Opera.
I have tryed before with self-signed certificate and secure WebSocket was working in Chrome and Chromium.

My webpage is located at https://warsoftheheroes.eu

login: zosia and password: zaqwsx

This is what you should see in Chrome javascript console when you log in:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://warsoftheheroes.eu:1025/chat' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled websocket.js?v=20170506:4 
WebSocket connection to 'wss://warsoftheheroes.eu:1025/main' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled websocket.js?v=20170506:5
```

This is what I see in WebSocket (PHPWS) server logs:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept(): Failed to enable crypto in [some path].../vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 126

Warning: stream_socket_accept(): Failed to enable crypto in [some path].../vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 126

PHP Warning:  stream_socket_accept(): accept failed: Success in [some path].../vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 126

Warning: stream_socket_accept(): accept failed: Success in [some path].../vendor/devristo/phpws/src/Devristo/Phpws/Server/WebSocketServer.php on line 126
```

[some path] is added by me instead of real path

What could be wrong? Certificate is working with Apache over HTTPS but fails to work with WebSocket over WSS.

-= E D I T =-

This is from my Apache SSL configuration:

SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128:AES256:HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK

-= EDIT 2 =-

There is output of nmap after openssl update:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 warsoftheheroes.eu

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-10 18:44 CEST
Nmap scan report for warsoftheheroes.eu (81.163.204.80)
Host is up (0.013s latency).
rDNS record for 81.163.204.80: pppoe-static-a-80.interblock.pl
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A
```

and

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 1025 warsoftheheroes.eu

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-10 19:07 CEST
Nmap scan report for warsoftheheroes.eu (81.163.204.80)
Host is up (0.015s latency).
rDNS record for 81.163.204.80: pppoe-static-a-80.interblock.pl
PORT     STATE SERVICE
1025/tcp open  NFS-or-IIS
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (brainpoolP256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution to my problem. There is this PHP SSL context option "verify_peer" which defaults to "true" which I think makes the server requests the client to provide a client certificate. So I set it to "false" and now Chrome/Chromium/Opera is working with WSS.

Comment: Ah nice, I think [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html) is related, pretty interesting

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the [Chrome Internals](http://chrome://net-internals) and start recording while the socket is attempting to connect, you'll see the following:

[image: net-internals]

The `ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED` is pretty explicit, and tell us that there's an issue with your certificate.

By looking at it, we can see you are using `RSA`, which is an obsolete key exchange. Instead you should use `DHE_RSA` or `ECDHE_RSA`. Even if you get no issue with https, this might be an issue for establishing a secure websocket connection, make sure you are using strong cyphers and key exchange mechanisms.

There is also the pretty basic issues of your phpws process not having read access to the certificate / pem file, the certificate being expired.. So you might want to double check that too, just in case.

Comment: I have DHE_RSA and ECDHE_RSA in my Apache SSL configuration, l edited my post and added my SSLCipherSuite

Comment: p.s. I think if it were issues with read access or expired certificate than WSS in Firefox would not work.

Comment: Yes you're right. Regarding the cypher suite, it looks good, but what I think is rather the key exchange that is not strong enough, and webkit is failing because of that. Can you try using `ECDHE_RSA` instead?

Comment: I recompiled openssl, apache, php and now it should work (Chrome/Chromium don't show obsolete key exchange), I don't know how to check what key exchange WSS is using.

Comment: Well now that's strange yes, everything seems to be good now. I know this is an Apache question. but could you try following [this](https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx) to proxy your websockets through nginx instead? Or at least try to set the correct headers in Apache. You can also try to add the `rejectUnauthorized` option for your websocket connection or add the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` env variable. If doing this suceed, there is definitely something wrong with the cert.